# Reading and printing the last number of integers from a binary file to the console

Tags: c, io

```
int read_last_ints(const char *file_name, int num_ints) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int integers;
    long int size;
    size_t nread;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    size = size - num_ints;
    fseek(fp, size, SEEK_SET);
    
    while ((nread = fread(&integers, 1, sizeof(int), fp)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", integers);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to create a function that reads the last integers from a binary file, however my code doesn't work as intended. When I try to test my code, it produces random numbers that don't make sence. If anyone has any advice, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. And please describe the problem better than "doesn't work". Give the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also describe what debugging you have done and what you have found.

Comment: `fseek()` and `ftell()` use positions in bytes. You need to divide by `sizeof(int)`

Comment: You might also need to use `"rb"` instead of `"r"` to read a binary file.  Using `"rb"` is crucial on Windows; it is harmless on Unix-like systems (because the C standard mandates support for `"rb"`, even though it is not necessary on Unix).

Comment: You need to change `size = size - num_ints;` to `size = size - num_ints * sizeof(int);` (multiplying by `sizeof(int)` rather than dividing by it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It did work. Thank you very much. This is my first time using fseek function and it works in such a weird way and it barely makes any sence to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to position backwards from the end of the file by the size of `num_ints` integers.

A minimalist change to your code is:

```c
int read_last_ints(const char *file_name, int num_ints) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int integers;
    long int size;
    size_t nread;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    size = size - sizeof(int) * num_ints;  /* MNC — minimum necessary change */
    fseek(fp, size, SEEK_SET);
    
    while ((nread = fread(&integers, 1, sizeof(int), fp)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", integers);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

However, you can make use of the `SEEK_END` option more effectively.  You should probably also use `"rb"` instead of `"r"` to read a binary file. Using `"rb"` is crucial on Windows; it is harmless on Unix-like systems (because the C standard mandates support for `"rb"`, even though it is not necessary on Unix).  This code also renames the variable `integers` to the singular `integer`.

```c
int read_last_ints(const char *file_name, int num_ints) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int integer;
    size_t nread;

    fseek(fp, -(long)(num_ints * sizeof(int)), SEEK_END);
    
    while ((nread = fread(&integer, 1, sizeof(int), fp)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", integer);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This saves a call to `fseek()`, `ftell()` and `rewind()`.  The `rewind()` was always superfluous, but you don't need to know the actual size of the file.  The `fseek()` call simply seeks to the relevant number of bytes before the end of the file.  You'd only have problems if the file is not big enough to hold that many integers (and it would just do its best, seeking to the start and reading as much as possible).